# Changes API: How to retrieve only modified file/folders. Currently it returns folders/files which are viewed also

Tags: google-drive-api

Changes.list API with token returns all changes including viewed/browsed folders and files. Is there any way to restrict this API to NOT return the viewed files or folders.

I am using Changes.getStartPageToken to get the start token and saved it.

Later on Google Drive, i added/deleted/renamed few files. I also viewed some files and folders.

In Changes.list with token retrieved above , it is returning the files and folders which are viewed also.
Is there any way to restrict this API to list only added/deleted/renamed/modified files alone ? I dont want to get the viewed files or folders.